# VB.NET Select from DataTable where field is not null

Tags: vb.net, linq, select, datatable, where-clause

I have a datatable where I'm trying to select all rows that have a date field within the past month:

```
Dim thisMonthQuery =
    From email In DataTablePickers.AsEnumerable() _
    Where email.Field(Of DateTime)("GenDateScheduled") >= New DateTime(curYear, curMonth, 1) _
    Select email

If thisMonthQuery.Any() Then
    Dim thisMonthData = thisMonthQuery.CopyToDataTable()
End If
```

The problem is that some of my rows have a null GenDateScheduled field, which throws the error "Cannot cast DBNull.Value to type 'System.DateTime'". I need to check if the field is null in my Select statement but I'm not sure how to do that. I assume it would be something like

```
Dim thisMonthQuery =
    From email In DataTablePickers.AsEnumerable() _
    Where email.Field("GenDateSchedule") Is Not Nothing And email.Field(Of DateTime)("GenDateScheduled") >= New DateTime(curYear, curMonth, 1) _
    Select email
```

but this isn't right.

Comment: DbNull is not the same as Nothing,  DBNull means there is no data, Nothing mean the object does not exist, so compare to DBNull.Value AndAlso you want the query to stop there and not execute the second part  where you cast the field to `DateTime`, so rather than `And` use `AndAlso`

Comment: `Nothing` and `DBNull.Value` are not the same thing.  `Where Not DBNull.Value.Equals(email.Field("GenDateSchedule") And email.Field(Of DateTime)("GenDateSchedule") >= New DateTime(curYear, curMonth, 1)` might get you where you're trying to go.